# How to import an addressfield with Feeds?

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

Using Drupal 7.10 with [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) 7.x-2.0-alpha4.  I'm trying to create a feeds importer to import node data stored in a csv file.  On the screen where you setup the mappings, my addressfield (that is part of my content type) doesn't appear in the drop down list of targets (whereas other fields of my content type do).

How can I get this to work?

I see some issues for this but being a Drupal newbie I can't really understand how to get this to work:

[Mapping Address Fields using Feeds and Feeds JSONPath Parser](http://drupal.org/node/1077552)

[Mapper for Feeds importers](http://drupal.org/node/1023068)

Do I need to switch to using the Dev release of feeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the links you posted, it looks like it's all wrapped up. Yes, try the current dev releases for Feeds.

Comment: Ah thanks that was it.  Switching to dev version of feeds (dated 2012-Jan-07) makes it work.

Comment: its always better if you use recommended version of the module